# Error 403 when trying to consume a Web Service from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis, soap

I created a Microsoft Dynamics NAV Web Service which provides customer information via SOAP. This WS is consumed on an ASP.NET website which is hosted on IIS8.
For user authentication I use the Windows Credentials.

On my local machine everything works smoothly, using both the Visual Studio built-in IIS Express and an additional installation of IIS 10.
Now I moved my website to our company's testing environment. Now when opening the website I get some strange behavior.

1. Accessing the website from http://localhost opens the website without any credential request
2. Accessing the website from the domain name resolves into a HTTP 403 error
3. Accessing the website from the IP resolves into a HTTP 403 error

The errorstack gives ma the following information from which I assume that the SOAP response fails to send the requested data.

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall) +690210
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters) +327
```

Comment: Did you enable CORS?

Comment: Yes, CORS is enabled but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem related connection behaviour and this problem will exits on local server only.

When you hosted your site on live server ,you need to remove proxy details becouse live server have direct internet connection with all web server.

Try this link how to define proxy list in webconfig.You have to bypass proxyserver
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex.aspx

Define proxy in server side call
http://forums.asp.net/t/1106772.aspx