# Websitepanel error while login into portal

Tags: asp.net, websitepanel

Facing this error while opening websitepanel portal:
Did anyone face this ? I did a lot of web search but nothing significant came up.

```
[WebException: The request failed with the error message:
--
<head><title>Document Moved</title></head>
<body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a HREF="https://127.0.0.1:9002/esAuthentication.asmx">here</a></body>
--.]
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall) +690210
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters) +327
   WebsitePanel.EnterpriseServer.esAuthentication.GetSystemSetupMode() +50
   WebsitePanel.Portal.Login.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3178
```

Comment: Does [Error 403 when trying to consume a Web Service from ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44645453/error-403-when-trying-to-consume-a-web-service-from-asp-net) help?

Comment: @AndrewMorton unfortunately that did not help :(

Comment: It's the only thing I found when gogling for "+690210". Perhaps you have some things you could add to the question to make it easier for someone else to see where the problem could be.